# Bootstrap: One column extending beyond fixed-width container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, multiple-columns

Using Bootstrap 4. I have a site using a fixed-width container. On some pages I would like the left portion of a row to contain only an image (img tag or background on a div, I'm not particular at this point) and I want that image to extend out of the fixed-width container to the edge of the window. The right portion is text that I want to keep within the container.

Hopefully this image explains it:

[image]

Can it be done?

Comment: Everything can be done my friend 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, approximately:

```
.left-bleed {
    margin-left: calc(-100vw / 2);
}

<figure class="left-bleed">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/KUfkX6gVwBU/2600x800">
</figure>
```

This will pull the image beyond the container and to the left edge of the viewport.

Helpful sources:

https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/
https://codepen.io/mor10/pen/baYLEB